# How to build a proper Database for a traffic analytics system?

Tags: php, mysql

How to build a proper structure for an analytics service? Currently i have 1 table that stores data about every user that visits the page with my client's ID so later my clients will be able to see the statistics for a specific date.

I've thought a bit today and I'm wondering: Let's say i have 1,000 users and everyone has around 1,000 impressions on their sites daily, means i get 1,000,000 (1M) new records every day to a single table. How will it work after 2 months or so (when the table reaches 60 Million records)?

I just think that after some time it will have so much records that the PHP queries to pull out the data will be really heavy, slow and take a lot of resources, is it true? and how to prevent that?

A friend of mine working on something similar and he is gonna make a new table for every client, is this the correct way to go with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Problem you are facing is I/O bound system. 1 million records a day is roughly 12 write queries per second. That's achievable, but pulling the data out while writing at the same time will make your system to be bound at the HDD level.

What you need to do is configure your database to support the I/O volume you'll be doing, such as - use appropriate database engine (InnoDB and not MyISAM), make sure you have fast enough HDD subsystem (RAID, not regular drives since they can and will fail at some point), design your database optimally, inspect queries with `EXPLAIN` to see where you might have gone wrong with them, maybe even use a different storage engine - personally, I'd use [TokuDB](http://www.tokutek.com/products/tokudb-for-mysql/) if I were you.

And also, I sincerely hope you'd be doing your querying, sorting, filtering on the database side and not on PHP side.

Comment: So suggesting to use InnoDB engine is hardware info for you? On top of that you opt to downvote an answer that actually helps someone design the system. Should you even be answering questions on SO with that kind of attitude that aids no one?

Comment: there is not attitude issue with me, but with you! anything and everything can constitute to design a system, right from PHP, hardware and just each and everything! better correct your attitude and get things right on SO!

Comment: I'm sorry but I won't get in such childish arguments with someone who apparently has no clue about what he's talking about.

Answer (score 1):

[Consider this Link to the Google Analytics Platform Components Overview page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/) and pay special attention to the way the data is written to the database, simply based on the architecture of the entire system.

Instead of writing everything to your database right away, you could write everything to a log file, then process the log later (perhaps at a time when the traffic isn't so high). At the end of the day, you'll still need to make all of those writes to your database, but if you batch them together and do them when that kind of load is more tolerable, your system will scale a lot better.

Comment: this is not an answer, should be a comment!

Comment: A link explaining nothing about scaling. -1 for misleading.

Comment: +1 It is a good link and related to the topic. It would help the OP to read it.

Comment: @PiTheNumber - no it's not. Scaling has to be done on MySQL level, not on PHP and Apache level that have nothing to do with I/O of 60 million rows in the database.

Comment: @N.B. and k102, this question is tagged with php and therefore php plays an important role in managing the traffic, in fact, its the most resource consuming thing!

Answer (score -1):

You could normalize impressions the data like this;

```
Client Table
{
  ID
  Name
}


Pages Table
{
  ID
  Page_Name
}

PagesClientsVisits Table
{
  ID
  Client_ID
  Page_ID
  Visits
}
```

and just increment visits on the final table on each new impression. Then the maximum number of records in there becomes (No. of clients * No. of pages)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work this way, the stats are pretty deep and the table stores a new record for every visit with the visitors IP and Country which means i can't really just write a number in `Visits`.

Comment: Got it - i thought your clients were the same as your visitors. You could easily just replace the "Clients" table with the "Visitors" table though and still use this technique. Bit difficult to comment without understanding your application a bit better.

Answer (score -1):

Having a table with 60 million records can be ok. That is what a database is for. But you should be careful about how many fields you have in the table. Also what datatype (=>size) each field has.

You create some kind of reports on the data. Think about what data you really need for those reports. For example you might need only the numbers of visits per user on every page. A simple count would do the trick.

What you also can do is generate the report every night and delete the raw data afterwards.

So, read and think about it.

Comment: The link still provides 0 information about scaling the database.

Comment: nice explanation to simplify things!